# Way to use equalsIgnoreCase to display an error in java

Tags: java

i am new to java. I am messing with some code to allow it to display an error instead of the whole system getting an error if the user inputs something it doesnt want, like a bunch of random letters. I want to use booleans, but i have no idea where to start. I used try and catch of a int, but im not sure what to do with a boolean. I was told to us a equalsIgnoreCase, but i have no idea where to add it in. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class bday
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String age = "0";

        age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What was your age yesterday?");

        int iage = 1;

        try
        {
            iage = Integer.parseInt(age);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks a lot, you broke it. CYA later.");
            return;
        }   

        String bday = "0";

         bday = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Was yesterday your B-Day? (True or False)");


         try
         {
             bage = Boolean.parseBoolean(bday);
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "WHY U MESS UP PROGRAM???.... BYE BYE!!");
            return;
         }

        if (bage == true){
            iage += 1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are now " + iage);
        }
        else if (bage == false){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Happy unbirthday!");
        }
        if (iage ==10){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congrats, double digits!");
        }
        if (iage >19){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "U aint a Teenager");
        }
        else if (iage < 13)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "U aint a Teenager");          

    }
}
```

What i am messing around with...

```
String bday = "0";
String str1 = "true";
String str2 = "false";

 bday = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Was yesterday your B-Day? (True or False)");


  boolean bage = bday.equalsIgnoreCase(str1);
  boolean bage2 = bday.equalsIgnoreCase(str2);

if (bage == true){
    iage += 1;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are now " + iage);
```

Comment: im not sure if i understood you ,you want to avoid multiple `JOptionPane...`?

Comment: Sorry, what i mean was for example, if the user answers "sfdsfd" to Was yesterday your B-Day, it would print out a message like "invalid characters."

Comment: SO i wanted to use equalsIgnoreCase with the boolean

Comment: Then a if else statement

Comment: I suggest that you turn off your computer and get a pencil and paper. Write down step by step, in English, what you want the program to do. When you have a clear understanding of the steps you want to take, then translating into Java code becomes easier.

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase()` doesn't display error messages. Your queation is essentially meaningless at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Boolean#parseBoolean()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean%28java.lang.String%29) alone doesn't work to validate characters because it returns `false` for any string that doesn't evaluate to `true` (ignoring the case of course). So, it would return `false` for junk characters as well instead of throwing a parse exception.

Hence, you need to test `bday` using `equalsIgnoreCase()` to validate that the user has entered one of the two values: `true` or `false`. This no longer requires you to handle an exception and so the `try-catch` is not required now.

```
if (bday.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || bday.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
    bage = Boolean.parseBoolean(bday);
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid choice: Enter true or false.");
    return;
}

if (bage){ // bage == true is unnecessary
    iage += 1;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are now " + iage);
} else { // no need to check the condition again
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Happy unbirthday!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped and worked!!!

Comment: `if(bage == true)` should be replaced as if (bage)

Comment: @nachokk Not my code mate. I only noticed there's no need for the `else if` check again so removed it here.

Comment: @user2593789, also take notice of nachokk's comment above and see how the `if else` block is written in my answer. Since, the `else` would only fire when the condition fails there's no need to check it again.

Comment: also check that `bday` could be `null`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know JOptionPane but a quick look shows that you should probably use "ConfirmDialog" instead of "InputDialog".   That should get you a int 0,1 value instead of a String that you need to parse.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog(java.awt.Component, java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29)